# Loading html file, javascript disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I changed the menu on my website so it replaces the main content on my page with html files using jquery instead of just href-ing the html pages. Something like:

```
$(function() {
  $('.new_page_title').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.main_content').load('new_page.html');
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
  });
});
```

For one of my pages I want to have a rotating sentence that gets randomly chosen from an array. Before, I was just doing it on page load, but now I have added a line to the above function to call the randomizer which looks like:

```
    function make_a_sentence() {
        var sentenceArray = [
            'digging holes in the back yard',
            'eating our vegetables',
            'doing something important',
            'building the future',
            'watering my plants',
            'propogating succulents',
            'watching Call the Midwife',
            'looking outside and dreaming of salvation',
            'poopin\'',
            'providing for my family',
            'watching you through your window',
            'digging around craigslist',
            'rotating my tires',
            'settling lawsuits'
        ];

        var selected = Math.floor(sentenceArray.length * Math.random());
        $("#id_of_div").html(sentenceArray[selected]);
}
```

And then calling make_a_sentence() at the end of the click function. When I just load the page, the sentence doesn't show up, and when I debug it inserts the sentence into the div until it gets to the end of the debug and then the sentence disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` function is asynchronous, you need to run code dependent on the loaded page's content in `load`'s callback (otherwise your changes gets rewritten as they occur before the load is completed), like:

```
$(function() {
  $('.new_page_title').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.main_content').load('new_page.html', function () {
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
      make_a_sentence()
    });
  });
});
```

See [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for reference.

Comment: Didn't realize load was async, this worked perfectly.